# Incorrect syntax near '00' error

Tags: c#, sql

please help me include a date into sql database, once it worked but now i just changed the forms (from main form to a add form) and it wont insert now.

this is my code and i've set it up to custom form dd-MM-yyyy and the fiend in the DB is Datetime type :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DgvFilterPopup;

namespace ExpertGeoMaster_v._1
{
    public partial class Ajout : Form

    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        public Ajout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Ajout_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // textbox1.SetValue(TextBoxHelper.ShowWatermarkProperty, box.Text == string.Empty);
        }

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::ExpertGeoMaster_v._1.Properties.Settings.Default.AgendaConnectionString);
            try
            {
                string sql = @"INSERT INTO Archive$ (DATE,TRAVAIL,SITUATION,DEMANDEUR,ACCORD,AV,solde,OBSAERVATION)  VALUES ("+ dateTimePicker1.Value.Date +",'" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "'," + textBox8.Text + "," + textBox9.Text + "," + textBox10.Text + ",'" + textBox11.Text + "')";

                SqlCommand execSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                cn.Open();
                execSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Ajouté avec succé !!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());//Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bk_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 new_form = new Form1();
            new_form.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox8_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')﻿ 
             {

             }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
            }
        }

        private void textBox10_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')﻿ 
             {

             }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
            }
        }

        private void textBox9_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')﻿ 
             {

             }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And what is your `sql` looks like exactly? Did you tried it on your management studio first? Is it works there? Debug your code. And what is your column types?

Comment: Not an answer, but please Google for "SQL injection" before you do too much more development work. You should _never_ build SQL queries like this.

Comment: Using parameters will probably also fix this issue because of the invalid datetime format.

Comment: Not sure what is what is wrong, but you can debug it. Put a debugger on the following line - SqlCommand execSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
Get the value of string sql and paste that in SSMS. You will get the syntax error.

Comment: When posting code samples try and remove all unrelated code as this only causes clutter and makes it harder for people to help you. As others posted beware of SQL injection with your current implementation.

Comment: When writing a question, don't include code bits that are unrelated to the problem: all those `textChanged` events you have there, for example, could be erased.

Comment: Thank you all for your tips and i am sorry for the unrelated portions of code sorry that this have disturbed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to pass a string representation of your date to your database engine and, as expected you fail. This is one of the reason to use a parameterized query. You create a DateTime parameter and let the database engine to figure how to read the date correctly without trying to interpreter a string. The other reason are Sql Injection and better performance.

So, said that this is an example

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Archive$
              ([DATE],TRAVAIL,SITUATION,DEMANDEUR,ACCORD,AV,solde,OBSAERVATION)  
              VALUES (@dt, @tr, @si, @de, @ac, @av, @so, @ob)";
using(SqlCommand execSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt",dateTimePicker1.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tr",textBox5.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@si",textBox6.Text );
    ..... and so on for the other parameters .....
    cn.Open();
    execSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Keep in mind that using AddWithValue is not the best option if you need the maximum performance and you need to convert the value for the parameters to the exact datatype expected by the underlying table. For example if `solde` is a decimal field then you need to convert the textbox content to a decimal value when adding the parameter to the collection (the reason is the same for the dates and strings. You leave the job of interpreting the decimal separator to your database engine)

There is another possible error in your query. The `DATE` is a `reserved keyword` in Sql Server (and probably in other database systems) so you should enclose it in square brackets

Comment: i will try this thank you Steve and sorry for the unrelated code.

Comment: Do not worry and remember to create parameters with the datatype expected by the underlying column otherwise you will get conversions errors. By the way, for the unrelated code you could simply edit your question and remove the unneeded lines

Comment: thank you very much Steve but i found that i did it this way but it didn't want to work maybe because i only did it for the date among other text variables. thank you very much any way.

Comment: Curious to know what doesn't work. Did you have any error messages?